# HTML syntax error when using onclick on an image tag

Tags: html, onclick

I can't spot the syntax error, to me it looks fine. Can anyone cast an eye, please?

> uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

It's line 16 which is where I'm calling the onclick function.

```js
function handleButtonClick() {
  console.log("Button click works!");
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-parent">
  <img id="circle" class="circle" src="./images/thanks_for_visiting_img.png">
  <img id="close-button" class="close-button" src="./images/close_green.png">
  <img id="quotes-button" class="quotes-button" src="./images/btn.png" onclick=”handleButtonClick()”>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you're using ” instead of "

So `onclick=”handleButtonClick()”` to `onclick="handleButtonClick()"`